# How to use Chrome as build in Sublime Text

Tags: build, sublimetext3

I'm trying to set up Chrome as a build system in Sublime Text on MacOs.

Tried using the New build menu option and plugged in:

```
{
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app": "Chrome"
}
```

It appears in list after I restart as build option but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the [build system documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html) has lots of examples if you want to add more functionality. However, for now, we'll just make a simple build system with one command - open the current file in Chrome.

Each build system needs to have a `"cmd"` key - the command you want to run - and optionally a `"selector"` key - a rule for selecting which types of files you want to run. For now, we'll just assume you only want to run HTML files. Select **`Tools → Build System → New Build System…`** and replace the contens with this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/Applications/Google Chrome.app", "$file"],
    "selector": "text.html"
}
```

Next, hit Save and save the file in the suggested folder with a name like `Chrome.sublime-build`. You don't need to restart for it to be visible in the Build System menu.

Now, when you want to view an HTML file in Chrome, you'll first select **`Tools → Build System → Chrome`**, then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to actually run the build. Chrome will stay selected as the current build system, so if you want to build again all you have to do is hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

If you do any work on Windows or Linux, the build command shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.